# How to connect html2pdf to nodemailer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nodemailer

I have an online form where applicants can download forms in pdf format using html2pdf plugin which I have installed. I also have nodemailer setup where applicants can send emails. But I do not know how to attach these two features. I would preferably want to strip the nodemailer form to just a submit button which will just send the pdf to an email of my choice using nodemailer.

Answer (score 0):

try below code its work for me. this [link](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/doc/output.md) help you to output html2pdf

```
$html2pdf->output('/absolute/path/file_xxxx.pdf', 'F');

transporter.sendMail({
  from: 'foo@bar.com'.
  to: 'bar@foo.com',
  subject: 'An Attached File',
  text: 'Check out this attached pdf file',
  attachments: [{
    filename: 'file.pdf',
    path: '/absolute/path/file_xxxx.pdf',
    contentType: 'application/pdf'
  }], function (err, info) {
     if(err){
       console.error(err);
       res.send(err);
     }
     else{
       console.log(info);
       res.send(info);
     }
  });
```

Comment: save generated pdf on the server then attach pdf to nodemailer sendMail function.

Comment: This code assumes that the user has a fiel path of f/absolute/path/file_xxxx.pdf in their computer

Comment: yes, required an absolute path for both localhost and server if you implement it into the server.

Comment: I used this code on my scripts tag `$html2pdf->output('/absolute/path/file_xxxx.pdf', 'F');`  

It says unexpected token >